# Use Flash Event System or build own Observer Design Pattern?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

In this cookbook someone advocates to build own Observer Design Pattern:
http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Using_Observer_Pattern_instead_of_Events-18232.html

Is it really faster as for performance ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes dispatching `Event` are slow, if performance are you goal you can go for your own event system or if you don't want to reinvent the wheel take a look at the [as3 signals library](https://github.com/robertpenner/as3-signals) from Robert Penner.

Answer (score 3):

The author of that article didn't claim that it is any faster in performance.

Instead, it is an alternate architecture.  Using the built-in eventing system, you subscribe to the publisher for events.  In this article, there is a singleton "data bus" that aggregates events that you subscribe to.

Ultimately, it solves a different problem, IMO.  The `ObserverManager` in that article sends out events that can be picked up by any object in the system.  It is great for events like "Play a movie", "Pause a movie", "Navigate to a link", etc where anyone can publish it and anyone can subscribe to it.  It is loosely coupled.  Kind of like a CB radio.

The eventing pattern in Flex/Flash, on the other hand, is more intimate.  A property on a model object changed, and the UI wants to display it, for instance.  Events go object to object.  It is more tightly coupled -- the objects need to have references to each other.  Kind of like a telephone call (or, since it is one-way, a telegraph, perhaps?)

Comment: I like your answer very much I cannot mark 2 good answers otherwise I'd do. Your blog is also very interesting, I'll visit it often.

Answer (score 0):

hi I think the Author's code can be optimized 
like
public function unsubscribe(observer : IObserver) : void {

```
       var index:int=indexof(observerData);
       if(index>0)
       {
             observerData.splice(index,1);

        }
```

}